# What is the best way to modify the JavaScript included in a scraped web page?

Tags: php, javascript, curl, preg-replace, screen-scraping

During a site scraping, I discovered several scraped functions in JavaScript that I need to modify because the code uses a relative path:

```
/UserControl/bla
```

I need to modify it to use absolute path:

```
www.domain-name.com/UserControl/bla
```

The problem is, those functions written in a separate file included by the scraped page. So far I can only stream that file using the PHP function `file_get_contents()`, change the part I need using `preg_replace`, and insert that script in the head section of the scraped HTML.  I don't have access to modify the included JavaScript file because it's on a server I don't have access to.

Is that the right way to do this?

Comment: Can't you directly change the .js files then?

Comment: Yup, i can't directly change it, sorry for not pointing out this crucial info first :D

Answer (score 1):

What I do in this cases is to declare JavaScript global variables with the objective to be constant values, then, I can access this variables from my included JS files, for example:

```
<script>
    Globals = {
        absoluteUrlPrefix: "<?= getAbsoluteUrlPrefix(); ?>"
    };
</script>
<script src="myjsfile.js"></script>
```

on `myjsfile.js`

```
...
var absoluteUrl = Globals.absoluteUrlPrefix+"/UserControl/bla";
...
```

Comment: In your solution, i assume that i need to have an access to the file that included in the page. The problem is i'm scrapping someone else's web, so i don't have any access to modify that file

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand the question.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace is an option, if it's just to show the web pages on your machine, you could also insert a base-path tag:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: Adding this to my script just messed up my other function. But, i appericiate your offer